# Why Video not saving given path using ffmpeg in android?

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I want to use ffmpeg to save video as given path in android.
I am using this command for saving the video but it doesn't work.
Where am I mistaken?

```
String[] command_try = new String[13];
    command_try[0] = "-i";
    command_try[1] = "/sdcard/Videos/Videos/f2a804f062384d4da3995d3bdce15610.mp4";
    command_try[2] = "-i";
    command_try[3] = "/sdcard/Videos/Videos/vidlogogif.gif";
    command_try[4] = "-filter_complex";
    command_try[5] = "overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:y=(main_h-overlay_h)/2";
    command_try[6] = "-pix_fmt";
    command_try[7] = "yuv420p";
    command_try[8] = "-c:a";
    command_try[9] = "copy";
    command_try[10] = "-preset";
    command_try[11] = "ultrafast";
    command_try[12] = "/sdcard/Videos/Videos/video11.mp4";
```

Comment: If you are unable you will receive an error message or an exception. Inform us.

Comment: @blackapps no there is no any error or exceptions

Comment: I think here is a command not executed, something went wrong with this

Comment: Have you added permission code for `Read/Write Internal Storage`,if not than add and also if you are using `android10` then add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` to your manifest file's `<application>...` tag

Comment: @VivekThummar can you please add code here for permission. thanks in adv!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First step is to add permissions to manifest file

   ```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   ```
2. Then add "Permission asking" code to java file

   call `hasPermission();` from your activity's `onCreate()` and here's your method :

   ```
    private void hasPermission() {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            final String[] s = new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                    ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                PermissionsDialog(s);
            } else {
                // do something when you got permission
            }
        } else {
            // do something when you got permission
        }
    }
   ```

Android app requires user permission on devices with `api >= 23`

This will ask for permission if your device's `api` version is `>= 23`, if it is below `23` or permission is already granted then next task will be performed.

if user `deny` permission then `PermissionsDialog(s);` will be called for asking permission.

```
    private void PermissionsDialog(final String[] s) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, s, Helper.REQUEST_PERMISSION);
    }
```

Then if user `allow` or `deny` permission it comes in this method :

```
    @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            if (requestCode == Helper.REQUEST_PERMISSION) {
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                for (int grantResult : grantResults) {
                    if (grantResult != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M &&
                            !ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, permissions[0])) {
                        startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
                                Uri.parse("package:" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID)), Helper.SETTINGS_CODE);
                    } else {
                        hasPermission();
                    }
                } else {
                    // do something when you got permission
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This method checks if permission is granted or not and it continues to ask for permission until you `allow` and if you `deny` for permission with `don't ask again` then we have to navigate user to App Setting Screen for allowing permission manually.

Now,when user comes from setting screen `onActivityResult(...)` of activity will be called, here call `hasPermission();` for recheck if user granted permission from setting screen or not which is as below :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == Helper.SETTINGS_CODE) {
        hasPermission();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for upvote, my reputation is not eligible

Comment: It's ok, do it later :-)

Comment: Hi can you please add Helper class here I dont know which helper class have to use here

Comment: It's just for use common variables and `Helper....` are variables for `requestCode` like : `int REQUEST_PERMISSION = 101` and `int SETTINGS_CODE = 101`.